# how to add UILabel within a UILabel?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

This question looks very usual.. but I had a problem yesterday, I have added a label in xib and created outlet for it, I want to have multiple lines, buttons inside that label, So I have decided to add new sub labels inside it...

```
UILabel *label;
label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:initial_rect];
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont smallSystemFontSize]];
label.text = sel_obj->start_time;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[xib_label addSubview:label]
```

When I tried like that, it was not working, then I have added the same label in self.view it works fine.. So what do I need to do when I want to add a label within a label which was added using xib. Am I missing anything here.. thanks...

Comment: try and check the value of `initial_rect` before your call to `initWithFrame`..

Comment: take UIView and then add labels and buttons to that view.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra is right. See if `initial_rect` falls within the visible rect of `xib_label`

Comment: @Krishnabhadra I have doubted that too.. I checked at that time itself.. Its value is within views frame only..

Comment: If you need multiple lines for UILabel then use setnumberiflines property of UILabel.

Comment: @sanjitshaw The property is `numberOfLines`.

Comment: sorry for the spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this situation long ago.

Just FYI :

I think the problem is the `initial_rect`, which is in the view's frame but out of the xib_label's frame.
The frame of label is relative to xib_label, not self.view.

You can try this :

```
UILabel *label;
CGRect rect = (CGRect){0, 0, 10, 10};
label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont smallSystemFontSize]];
label.text = sel_obj->start_time;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[xib_label addSubview:label];
```

Change the backgroundColor to red to see the label clearly.

And if you want to show multiple lines in a label, you can :
`label.numberOfLines = 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try after the above comments to bring subview to front `[xib_lable bringSubViewToFront:label];`